# Selecting distinc rows with conditional select and sum

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL selection what I cannot make it to work.
My simplified `order` table looks like this:

```
+----+------------+----------------+-------+----------------+
| id | partner_id | personal_price | price | modified_price |
+----+------------+----------------+-------+----------------+
|  1 |          1 |            500 |   900 | NULL           |
|  2 |          1 |            700 |  1100 | 1400           |
|  3 |          2 |            400 |   800 | NULL           |
+----+------------+----------------+-------+----------------+
```

I the `total_price` should be the `modified_price` if it's set, or the `price` if not. And I also want to DISTINCT the rows by partners and summarise the `total_price` and `personal_price` and calculate the diffrenece as `partner_price`.

And the result should look like this:

```
+------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| partner_id | total_price | personal_price | partner_price |
+------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
|          1 |        2300 |           1200 |          1100 |
|          2 |         800 |            400 |           400 |
+------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
```

So far the code what's not working is:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT partner_id,
  SUM ( CASE WHEN price_modified IS NULL 
    THEN price 
    ELSE price_modified END ) as total_price,
  SUM ( presonal_price ),
  total_price - personal_price as parnter_price
  FROM orders
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `group by partner_id` and not use distinct:

```
select
  partner_id,
  sum(coalesce(modified_price, price)) total_price,
  sum(personal_price) personal_price,
  sum(coalesce(modified_price, price) - personal_price) partner_price
from orders
group by partner_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xuvVhobD73c6441Rk5m49A/1).
Results:

```
| partner_id | total_price | personal_price | partner_price |
| ---------- | ----------- | -------------- | ------------- |
| 1          | 2300        | 1200           | 1100          |
| 2          | 800         | 400            | 400           |
```

Comment: That's works, thanks! I edited the table where every `id` was 1, so the id is just a row id, the group by is correctly the `partner_id`